# How to change Blenders User Interface

Tags: interface, edit-mode

Just wondering if it is possible to change Blenders User Interface/Interaction to the standard setup for windows programs?

I am aware the select with left/right option, what I am referring to is how blender tends to hide tasks or change the standard method for interactions *(such as having right click default to selection blender limited it self by removing all the standard right click interactions with objects)* or blender hides the tasks behind lots of confirmations. Most are understandably nice to have, however I do not see an option that lets me stop all future confirmations of X,Y or Z interactions like most software.
A simple example is Deleting something, Select it, hit delete, then it always requires a confirmation even when the action is undoable it still requires you to confirm your action.

Answer (score 0):

Please see User Preferences (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>) for options. You can use left click to select if you wish:

[image]

You might need some time to adjust to the standards inside Blender. It might be a better and smoother experience if you tried to learn using it before customizing it too much as that might be a lot more dificult than it might seem because of the complexity of the software and the amount of funcions in it. By trying to conform Blender to what you are used to you are likely to miss out on many great features and workflows Blender has to offer.

Comment: Thanks for the info however as stated in the question I am aware of the left/right click option and thus that is not the question or an answer. As to adjusting to blenders standards that too is not the question, since you can adjust to something and still prefer it to be different thus why Blender decided to change the user selection method. As for learning blenders default workflows it has before customizing it, well that is exactly what I have done and I am now attempting to learn if there are options to allow the user to define a custom workflow.

Comment: You will need to be a lot more specific about what it is exactly that you wish to change and what you wish to change it to if you want to get help.